# Failed to read schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-context.xsd

Tags: java, spring

I was getting the following error message while i was working with Spring with IntelliJ:

> Failed to read schema document
>   'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-context.xsd',
>   because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
>   read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

Help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong url in **xsi:schemaLocation**

Instead if using:

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-context.xsd

I should have to used:

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

That solved my problem.
I crossed checked this with firing url into browser where within beans no spring-context.xsd was available.

Hope some of you can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

@Indrajeet : The proper spring.xml or application-context.xml format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this latest one. I faced the same issue and I got it solved by using this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- bean definitions here -->

</beans>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).